# Are amnesia stories good for RPGs?

Tags: gm-techniques, story

I've noticed that some plot types seem hard to pull off in Role Playing Games.

Are Party Amnesia plots good for the medium?  Do they require any special handling? Should the players be in on it (they'll know their characters have amnesia but how much should they know about prior to)?  If the players aren't in on it, how should their characters' histories be handled?  How do you handle skills?

Comment: There are many disparate questions here, and most of these are opinion-based ones you should bring to a forum.

Comment: Are you referring to a case of [_in media res_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_medias_res)?  If so, [here are](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/guidelines-for-writing-a-convention-scenario/5507#5507) some [related posts on the topic](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/how-to-begin-a-role-playing-scenario-in-medias-res).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I think I'm talking about a subset. Like KoToR the character didn't know they were Revan, or really anything about themselves. in media res seems like it's the same thing, but from what I'm reading it doesn't imply that the character doesn't know only the audience. I'm talking about where the characters don't know.

Comment: If you specify a system and give more details about your situation, this *might* become answerable in the Stack Exchange format. As it is, an answer recommending A Penny For My Thoughts would be as good as an answer detailing memory-modification spells in D&D 3.5 or an answer talking about the pitfalls of the social contract in player/GM/character knowledge gaps.

Comment: RPG.SE search, keyword "amnesia" and found a few dozen related questions. Examples: [1](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27756/manage-a-player-character-suffering-amnesia/27758#27758), [2](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/character-driven-fantasy-adventure-with-infrequent-combat/10890#10890), [3](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9714/what-kind-of-sf-horror-does-eclipse-phase-lend-itself-to/53249#53249), [4](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16789/as-a-gm-how-do-i-encourage-pcs-to-share-and-play-out-their-backstories/16799#16799). May help you refine your question.